# manually call a function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

How do you do this? like PHP has call_user_func

I'm trying to pass a callback function to jQuery.animate(), like this

```
...
complete: function(){ 
  // do_something 
  call_function(my_callback); // here need to call my_callback
}
...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply call it like you would any function

```
 my_callback();
```

JavaScript also has a call method that some people prefer

```
 my_callback.call();
```

Here's a link I found with some extra information regarding the call method. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Call

Comment: Yeah certain functionalities in php were definitely an after thought. :P  Its definitely makes more sense in js, but that is just my opinion.